# Extended Event Session Keeps Stopping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

A few months ago I added an extended event to track blocked processes and deadlocks, with a file output to track occurrences.

Every now and again, I check the log file, but find that the extended event has stopped, when I "Start Session" again through SSMS, it picks up again and logs as expected.

How can I ensure that this runs 24/7?
Is it possibly failing somewhere and there's a log of errors that I'm unaware of?

[image: Output File(s)]

[image: Selected Events]

Comment: Is your session defined with `STARTUP_STATE=ON` so that it's automatically started when the SQL instance starts?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem, it was off and we have had a couple of maintenance restarts lately. Could you put that in an answer and I'll accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your Extended Event session is defined with `STARTUP_STATE=OFF` so it is not started automatically when SQL Server is restarted.

Change the session to `STARTUP_STATE=ON` to ensure it's always running (unless stopped manually):

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [blocked_process] ON SERVER 
    WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON);
```